# Using the long variable type in for loops

Tags: java, loops, long-integer

I've been trying to work using some very large numbers. I've been having trouble using the **long** variable type in a for loop.

so let's say I want to use `600000000000`

I tried to make a simple for loop that iterates through 600000000000 times. This is my attempt (java):

```
    long n = 2342345234L;
    for (int i = 1; i==n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

I run the code, and it outputs nothing. I've tried changing the `int i = 1` to `long i = 1` and `long i = 1L`

I have no experience with the **long** variable type so I would appreciate an explanation of what I need to change in my code and/or a simple explanation of the differences between **int** and **long**

I have checked for duplicate posts but they all seem to be more centered around people not putting L after their numbers rather than my issue where the loop seems to terminate instantly.

*Thanks to all replies. Worth noting to anybody reading that the solution to my problem was not relevant to the **long** variable type in any way. Simply my incorrect implementation of the for loop*

Comment: for such large numbers use `while` with long type vars

Comment: `i==n` is always `false` in your case. Try again.

Comment: Are you experiencing an issue or what? What's your question? If you're asking about the difference between int and long, it's that long can hold larger numbers than int can (and therefore is slightly more expensive to use).

Comment: Int holds values up to 2^32 -  1 while long holds up to 2^64 - 1, I believe. other than that, I think you only need the L if the value isn't already larger than an int. The problem is the conditional, though

Comment: @cricket_007 *"I think you only need the L if the value isn't already larger than an int"* That value is larger than `int`'s max.

Comment: @Tom Correct, so I'm saying I don't think the L is needed

Comment: @cricket_007 Without the `L`, you get a compile error: *The literal 2342345234 of type int is out of range*. The number  is greater than 2147483647 ([`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)).

Comment: @cricket_007 It is needed, because ***it is larger than `int`***. Every number literal without an indicator (like `L`, `F` and `D`) is treated as `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `long` or `int`, it's due to the fact that you loop while `i == n` which is false on the first iteration because `1` is not equal to `2342345234`.

You can instead loop while `i < n`:

```
long n = 2342345234L;
for (long i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: You should mention, that you've changed that type of `i` as well.

Comment: Ah thanks. I've just started using java so stupidly I was thinking that the code ran   **until** the condition was met rather than **while**

Answer (score -1):

change `i==n` to `i < n` . **You need to first learn how loop works.**

```
long n = 2342345234L;
for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: (You oversaw the **int** i, hence someone downvoted.)